# does word2vec tutorial example imply potential sub-optimal implementation?

Tags: tensorflow

**Machine Specs:**

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- 16GB RAM
- nvidia TitanX

(btw
There is a bug in word2vec example(both word2vec.py and word2vec_optimized.py) that it would run into error if no device directive is given. I add a with tf.device('/cpu:0') to work around)

**Hyper-Parameter Setup:**

- the default model hyper-parameter + 8 concurrent threads
- use text8 as training data and questions-words.txt as test.

**Profiling Result:**

- word2vec_optimized.py: 171891 words/sec ( 8 threads)
- word2vec_optimized.py: 9258 words/sec (8 threads)

(the optimized version is comparable with Mikolov's original implementation, and the standard one is significantly slower)

CPU utilization during training is roughly the same (the optimized version is a little bit higher)

I reviewed the code of two the implementations, and I couldn't figure out why the standard implementation (word2vec.py) is 20x slower than the C++ hand-coded kernel(word2vec_kernels.cc)

The word2vec_kernel.cc does not seem to do anything special to speed up (it first do a batch random sampling and then run a loop over samples in a single batch)

The word2vec.py version doesn't seem to be sub-optimal to me either, it uses the standard tensorflow operations and the batching seems to be suitable.

Have you guys ever do any internal profiling to figure out what is the performance bottleneck of the standard version? Would the performance bug be a threat to the training performance of other neural networks in general?

Comment: Voting to close as question is off topic: Have you guys ever do any internal profiling to figure out what is the performance bottleneck of the standard version? Would the performance bug be a threat to the training performance of other neural networks in general? See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  or try asking at [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/discuss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you guys ever do any internal profiling to figure out what is the performance bottleneck of the standard version?
A: Yes. We did. The profiling led our decision to write the optimized version.

Would the performance bug be a threat to the training performance of other neural networks in general?
A: It's a complex question and the answer depends on scenario. I'd not make such a generalization. In many other models (at least for some that I played with), the computation is often dominated by "heavy operations" like matmul, convolution, etc. In those models, the loss and its gradient's computation is relatively cheap. On the other hand, word2vec is very special in that the training step is basically embedding lookup + loss's gradient + apply gradient, because these operations are not "fused", executing these operations incurs much higher memory bandwidth. TF plans to develop compiler optimization techniques to fuse such operations automatically and that will avoid , to some degree, the need to manually fuse operations to optimize performance.